# how do I make the taillength update with age?

Tags: java

```
//Srivet av Jonathan Arnfjell joar6216

public class Dog {
    private String name; // name of dog
    private int age; // in years
    private int weight; // in pounds
    private String breed; // breed of dog
    private double tailLength; // Length of tail
    private double div = 10;
    private double smallTail = 3.7;
    private double ageDouble;
    private double weightDouble;

    public Dog(String name, String breed, int age, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.ageDouble = age;
        this.weightDouble = weight;
        this.tailLength = ageDouble * weightDouble / div;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public double getTailLength() {
        if (breed.equalsIgnoreCase("tax") || breed.equalsIgnoreCase("dachshund")) {
            return smallTail;
        } else {
            return tailLength;
        }
    }

    public void setAge(int newAge) {
        if (newAge < age) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Age goes up!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else
            age = newAge;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + breed + " " + age + " " + weight + " " + getTailLength();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Dog d1 = new Dog("Fluffy", "tax", 5, 6);
        Dog d2 = new Dog("Fido", "Fakehund", 7, 15);

        System.out.println(d2);
        System.out.println(d2.getTailLength());
        d2.setAge(9);
        System.out.println(d2);
        System.out.println(d2.getTailLength());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `setAge()` function to this:

```
public void setAge(int newAge) {
  if (newAge < age) {
      System.out.println("ERROR: Age goes up!");
      System.exit(0);
  } else
      age = newAge;
      this.tailLength = age * weightDouble / div;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to have 1 source of truth. If the tail length is generated based on other values, then you shouldn't store the value of tail length, the getTailLength() function could calculate the tail length every time it is called.

You could recalculate tail length every time tail length is called, to make sure the tail length is updated before it is used. But if you are calculating it every time it is used, then there doesn't seem to be a point in storing it.

Another option could be to use something similar to a simplified observer pattern. When weight or age is updated, call a method that updates the tail length.

To me though it makes the most sense not to store it, and to simply calculate it when you want it.